# Same code using floats on two computers gives two different results

Tags: c++, image-processing, floating-point

I've got some image processing code in C++ which calculates gradients and finds straight lines in them with the hough transformation algorithm. The program does most of the calculations with floats.

When I run this code on the same image on two different computers, one Pentium IV running latest Fedora, the other a Core i5 latest Ubuntu, both 32 bit, I get slightly different results. E.g. I have after some lengthy calculation 1.3456f for some variable on the one machine and 1.3457f on the other. Is this expected behavior or should I search for errors in my program?

My first guess was, that I'm accessing some uninitialized or out-of-bounds memory but I did run the program through valgrind and it can't find any errors, also running multiple times on the same machine always gives the same results.

Comment: Move to double (use of float is only common if you want to save space). You may still get some slight variation but the relative magnitude will be smaller.

Comment: It's worth scrutinizing your code to make sure you're using as stable an algorithm as possible.  For example, if you add two numbers that sum to nearly zero (e.g., 1.000012 + (-1.000006)) the result will lose most of its significant digits.  There are often ways to get better answers either by reformulating the mathematical expressions or by doing only certain intermediate calculations in higher precision.  You'll retain most of the performance benefit of using floats instead of doubles while getting answers with the precision you deserve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not uncommon and it will depend on your compiler, optimisation settings, math libraries, CPU, and of course the numerical stability of the algorithms that you are using.

You need to have a good idea of your accuracy requirements and if you are not meeting these then you may need to look at your algorithms and e.g. consider using double rather than float where needed.

Comment: True. I would add that compiling with -ffloat-store flag (in GCC) might help to have the same result in both platforms.

Answer (score 6):

For background on why given source code might not result in the same output on different computers, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  I doubt this is due to any deficiency of your code unless it performs aggregation in a non-deterministic way eg. by centrally collating calculation results from multiple threads.

Floating point behaviour is often tunable per compiler options, even to the level of different CPUs.  Check your compiler docs to see if you can reduce or eliminate the discrepancy. On Visual C++ (for example) this is done [via /fp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Is it due to the a phonomena called machine epsilon?

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon
```

There are limitations on flaoting-point number. The fact that floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and that floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, leads to many surprising situations. This is related to the finite precision with which computers generally represent numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the same C++ instructions can be compiled to different machine instructions (even on the same CPU and certainly on different CPUs) depending on a large number of factors, and the same machine instructions can lead to different low-level CPU actions depending on a large number of factors. In theory, these are supposed to be semantically equivalent, but with floating-point numbers, there are edge cases where they aren't.

Read ["The pitfalls of verifying floating-point computations" by David Monniaux](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/28/14/29/PDF/floating-point-article.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I will also say that this is very common, and probably not your fault.

I spent a lot of time in the past trying to figure out the same problem.

I would suggest to use `decimal` instead of `float` and `double` as long as your numbers do not refer to scientific calculations but to values like prices, quantities, exchange rates, etc.

Comment: A good idea for e.g. a database, but not really applicable to internal calculations, as there is usually no hardware support for decimal (though I seem to recall some mainframes have it).

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal, unfortunately.

There are libraries which can produce identical results everywhere--see http://www.mpfr.org/ for an example. But the performance cost is substantial and it's probably not worth it unless exact identical results are the *most* important criterion.

I've actually written a closed-source library which implemented floating-point math in the integer unit, in order to make floats provide identical results on multiple platforms (Intel, AMD, PowerPC) across different compilers. We had an app which simply could not function if floating-point results varied. It was quite a challenge, though. If we could do it again we'd have just designed the original app in fixed-point, but at the time it was too much code to rewrite.

Comment: Note that MPFR offers more than just identical results, it also aims for answers that are correct to within the precision of the result type.

Answer (score 0):

Either this is a difference between the internal representation of the float, making slightly different results, or perhaps it is a difference in the way the float is printed to the screen? I doubt that it is your fault...